# Windows 10 quick access does not group items

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

The quick access folder in the Windows 10 explorer usually groups the items by type, first all folders and then all files:

[image]

I have one machine where for one user that grouping is missing:

[image]

For other users on the same machine the grouping is as it should be. The group and sort options in the context menu on quick access are disabled, but that seems to be normal, as it is disable for other users too. I tried setting the options back to defaults in the explorer options, but that didn't do the trick. Apart from that I can't find any option to turn grouping on or off for quick access.

- In other folders the sorting and grouping works as normal
- Changing the view mode (tiles, small icons, large icons etc.) makes no difference (this came up in a now deleted answer)
- I browsed through the registry, looking for obvious options, finding none
- It works correctly for other user accounts on the same machine
- The machine is joined to a domain, there are no group policies set that should affect this
- The user with the problem is not a domain user, it's a local account

How can I turn grouping in quick access back on?

Comment: Meanwhile the computer in question has been reinstalled and the problem has vanished. I'm afraid this mystery will remain unsolved.

Answer (score 5):

I recently had this issue, which I fixed by using the "Reset Folders" button under the "View" tab, in the "Folder Options" property menu.

[image: folder options properties window]

I suspect the quick access folder is handled uniquely by Windows Explorer, and as such doesn't do its ordering and sorting by the "normal" means (i.e using the "Sort By" and "Order By" settings) which is why they're greyed out.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in the question I already tried to set it back to defaults. And these settings are only greyed out for this specific user,  it works for other users on the same machine and on other machines.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider My apologies - I didn't realize that those options were not grayed out on the other machines. I find that strange however, and will check with other computers near my person running Win10, since I don't remember any of them ever having those settings not grayed out. Also while you might have tried the "restore to default" button I was under the impression that only applied for the settings on the "General" tab, and that the "Reset Folder" action applied to a different set of settings. Should I find anymore information on this issue I shall pass it along.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider for reference here is my Quick Access in Explorer with the Ribbon showing: http://puu.sh/nN0nX/5cb049ad43.png

Comment: @GeraldSchneider After checking with two other instances of Windows 10, it seems that the "Group By" setting being disabled for Quick Access is the norm. http://puu.sh/nN8bp/28653db18e.png & http://puu.sh/nN8kZ/d81df25c9a.png

Comment: I know that. I work in IT and have literally hundreds of PCs at my disposal to test this. The point of my question is not that it is greyed out, the point is that on one machine for only one user grouping is disabled and greyed out. For everyone else it is enabled and greyed out.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider again my apologies - you clearly know what you're doing. I wish you well on your quest, and hope you find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but this issue pops up occasionally. Don't know why the shell sometimes hiccups and loses the GroupBy info for Qucik Access, but as others have noted, the Group by > option is grayed out when viewing Quick Access.

Here's the PowerShell to 'surgically' remove only the corruptted saved view for Quick Access without losing all saved fodler views:

```
$Bags = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\*\Shell\*'
$QAID = '{24ccb8a6-c45a-477d-b940-3382b9225668}'
gci $Bags | ?{$_.PSChildName -like $QAID} | remove-item
get-process explorer | stop-process
```

One-liner version:

```
ri 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\*\Shell\{24ccb8a6-c45a-477d-b940-3382b9225668}'; gps explorer | spps
```

Keith

Answer (score 0):

Click on the View(Ansicht) menu --> Click on Group by --> Type

PS: I don't know what these items are called in German so you'll have to figure out them yourself. Good luck.

Here's a screenshot showing the menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7WVD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I had to reset folder view options by using a .BAT file.
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/17707-reset-folder-view-settings-default-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1222516)